# Почему не загружается изображение из приложения в Firebase Storage?

Tags: android, kotlin

Мне нужно сделать возможность выбранное изображение в приложении загрузить в Firebase Storage, я связал его со своим приложением.
Если проверка всех полей успешна, переходит в метод где создается айди из даты, а затем уже по сути должно загружаться изображение

```
private fun HomeInformation() {
    val value: Calendar = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        Calendar.getInstance()
    } else {
        TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < N")
    }
    val DateFormat  = SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy")
    saveCurrentDate = DateFormat.format(value.time)

    val TimeFormat  = SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss")
    saveCurrentTime = TimeFormat.format(value.time)

    RandomKey = saveCurrentDate + saveCurrentTime

    val filePath: StorageReference = HouseImageRef!!.child(ImageUri!!.lastPathSegment + RandomKey + ".jpg")

    val UploadTask: UploadTask = filePath.putFile(ImageUri!!)

    UploadTask.addOnFailureListener { e ->
        val message = e.toString()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Ошибка: $message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }.addOnSuccessListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Изображение успешно загружено.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        UploadTask.continueWithTask { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                throw task.exception!!
            }
            downloadImageUrl = filePath.downloadUrl.toString()
            return@continueWithTask filePath.downloadUrl
        }.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                downloadImageUrl = task.result.toString()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Фото сохранено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                SaveProductInfoToDatabase()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Далее сохранение в базу

```
private fun SaveProductInfoToDatabase() {
    val productMap = HashMap<String, Any>()

    productMap["put"] = RandomKey!!
    productMap["date"] = saveCurrentDate!!
    productMap["time"] = saveCurrentTime!!
    productMap["infoV"] = infoView!!
    productMap["numberV"] = phoneNumber!!
    productMap["image"] = downloadImageUrl!!
    productMap["costV"] = costView!!
    productMap["locationV"] = locationView!!
    productMap["roomsV"] = roomsView!!
    productMap["squareV"] = squareView!!
    productMap["tpHouseV"] = typeHouse


    HouseReference?.child(RandomKey!!)?.updateChildren(productMap)?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Объявление добавлено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val AdIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(AdIntent)
        } else {
            val message = task.exception.toString()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ошибка: $message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Но когда захожу в Firebase Storage, там нет загруженного изображения. Ошибок тоже никаких не выводит. Помогите, срочно нужно для курсовой...

Comment: У вас там кругом тосты, что они говорят? Что за ошибка?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja в принципе сообщения в тостах говорят за себя в чем суть, а тосты с ошибкой должны выдавать ошибку с пояснением в чем именно сбой. Но суть в том что у меня ни один из этих тостов даже не высвечивается, просто закрывается активити при нажатии на кнопку и в базе не появляется загруженного изображения

Comment: Может активити не просто закрывается, а крашится?

Comment: @Михаил ну опять же, ошибок нигде не вылазит, если что-то не так с кодом, хотелось бы услышать что исправить, а так сам я не знаю что можно исправить

Comment: С codeStyle точно нужно поработать. Есть предположение что проблема где то в другом месте  , и посмотри все таки в logcat error

Comment: @Михаил Сначала была ошибка о том что API неправильный, я заменил старое значение в values.xml  новым из google-services (надеюсь так можно делать, по крайней мере ошибка пропала). Тем не менее в storage всё еще ничего не загружается.
Есть еще 3 ошибки:
Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000;
Fail to get file list (имя пакета);
getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Comment: Приложение крашится от NPE - "getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array". Тебе надо разобраться - в каком месте кода ошибка (смотри ниже этой строчки логи которые указывают в твой код) и пофиксить ее. Будут проблемы - прикладывай сюда полный стек ошибки и код.

Comment: @Михаил Ну у меня вылазило две таких ошибки, я убрал один массив для спинера, одна ошибка ушла, а больше у меня вроде как и нет массивов. 
Логи: 
getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
App measurement initialized, version: 60000
To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
To enable faster debug mode event logging run:

Comment: @Михаил Если так посмотреть на код, то ошибка должна быть в коде из описания, но я не могу понять что там может вызывать её... Остальной код уже либо валидация полей, инициализация, открытие галереи (всё это прекрасно работает)

Comment: @Neito когда есть стэк ошибки - то там можно понять в каком методе, в какой строчке кода она произошла, это очень удобно. Без этого искать ошибку гораздо сложней, а в нашем случае - это просто гадание на кофейной гуще. Что бы тебе помогли - приложи стэк ошибки - строчку "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array App measurement" и строчек 20 ниже.